# Can't retrieve C# cookies from angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am sharing a cookie value from one request to another in .net web api as mentioned bellow,

1st Request :-

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyAttendance/loginTask")]
public async Task<string> loginTask()
{    
    //some code

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("userAuth");

    cookie["sessionId"] = sessionID;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    cookie.Expires = now.AddYears(50);    

    return "Successful";
}
```

2nd Request :-

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/MyAttendance/GetUser")]
        public string GetUser()
        {

            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userAuth"];
            var sessionId = cookie["sessionId"];

            //some code

            return sessionId;   
        }
```

When I access the 1st request, the `sessionID` will be stored in the `httpcookie` so that I can get this cookie value from the 2nd request.I can do this process successfully from the .net web api(backend)and from postman.but when I do the same process from the angular(frontend),1st request works successfully but 2nd request will not execute it gives me following error because cookie value cannot be accessed.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Calling Requests from the angular project(Frontend) :-

```
 getAuthentication(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/loginTask').pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json()));
  }

  getUserData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/GetUser").pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json()));;
  }
```

I have no idea about this problem.Can someone explain me how to resolve this?

Comment: WebAPI is not a stateful, once you made a request all connection made all process/variable initialization etc and once it finished it vanish it all!

Comment: Not true, you can use cookies or some kind of other authorization (like Authorization id) to validate the credentials. Cookies should be sent with every request if that's the authorization texhnique you have chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a CORS issue. You need to user with credentials option

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

```
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });


  getAuthentication(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/loginTask', options).pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json()));
  }

  getUserData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:2073/api/MyAttendance/GetUser", options).pipe(
      map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json()));;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is that! If the API is not a stateful then how can the variable and values of the first request can be accessible on the second request! Correct me If I am wrong!

Comment: The api is (a bit) stateful by default, since we are using cookies. Any kind of authorization mean some kind of state and it can't be avoided. The thing is that the client maintains the state so the server side does not need to keep any.